Syntax for like operator in teradata sql assistant
What is the correct syntax for like operator that can be used for multiple values in the filter condition while writing a query in teradata SQL assistant?
For example a column named uniq_id is there with 5 sample values. Now what syntax should I write in the where condition using the like operator?
I tried writing the query like this:
Where uniq_id like 'example1%' or uniq_id like 'example2%'…

Is this the correct syntax?

Maybe just: Where uniq_id like 'example%' to get all 5?

Please provide sample data and the output you'd like to obtain from that data. See Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question. Also, your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to go through the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting. You'll find [ask] a good resource when you're just starting out here.

Hi Paul, thanks for the reply but what if i have 5 completely different sample values?

like any ('a%','b%','c%','d%','e%')
